# How i can hide object from viewport and render at the same time?

Tags: interface

To hide object from viewport i need click icon "eye" or "monitor" in outliner, to hide object from render i need click icon "camera". I do 2 actions but I want to do it in 1 action.

In my opinion it is logical -> if you hide object from viewport it should automatically hide from render.

Any solution?

Comment: This is really arguable. You may want to hide objects which block your view from your viewport while you work on other parts, and still see it in your render, like volumetrics or particles for example.

Comment: i could answer that one but i'm already too lazy to click on two buttons

Comment: Though you can "click drag release" over the two icons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just click and drag on the icons in the Outliner:

[image: Just click and drag]

Comment: Am wondering if there is a way to upvote both question and answer in one click... maybe this can be asked on the meta? ; ) ... ok I'll do for your answer.